# SpreadSheetGear - Show only one sheet from a file in WPF MVVM

Tags: spreadsheetgear

I'm displaying an Excel workbook in a SpreadSheetGear WorkbookView in an MVVM WPF application. But the workbook has 9 sheets, I only want to display one of them. I know the name of the sheet. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. You need to go through the IWorkbook's WindowInfo property.

```
Workbook.WindowInfo.ActiveWorksheet = book.Worksheets["my workbook"];
```

This activates the sheet you want to display. Then you disable switching sheets by disabling workbook tabs:

```
Workbook.WindowInfo.DisplayWorkbookTabs = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to hiding the entire sheet tab bar would be to set all worksheets' ISheet.[Visible](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.ISheet~Visible.html) property to [SheetVisibility](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.SheetVisibility.html).Hidden or VeryHidden except for the sheet you want to display.  Example:

```
foreach (ISheet sheet in book.Sheets)
{
    if (sheet.Name != "My Visible Sheet")
    {
        sheet.Visible = SheetVisibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Are there any advantages or downsides to either approach, that may not be apparent?

Comment: One problem with simply hiding the Tab Bar, at least in Excel, is that the user could still use the keyboard shortcuts [Ctrl]+[Page Up] or [Ctrl]+[Page Down] to switch through and select any of sheet tabs.  SpreadsheetGear's WorkbookView does not support these keyboard shortcuts and so is less of an issue.  If you actually hide the sheets, then this workaround is a total non-issue because you cannot select and make visible a hidden sheet.

Comment: Another consideration with SpreadsheetGear and the WorkbookView--if you provide access to the WorkbookExplorer dialog (available from the WorkbookView's context menu), then all non-VeryHidden sheets will be accessible and selectable from this dialog, regardless of whether or not the tab bar is visible.